# Collision between ball and paddle's corners!! iOS

Tags: ios, collision

When the ball hits the paddle from the corners or left and right side, the ball goes into the paddle from one side and goes out of it from the other side.. How can I fix this problem? Thanks..

My code:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame,paddle.frame))
{
            [self bounceBall]; 
}

- (void) bounceBall
 {
    direction.x *= 1;
    direction.y *=-1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20456/a-more-sophisticated-ball-paddle-collision-algorithm-for-breakout) will be helpful for you to got solution for the above problem.